# How to send intent between Activities in different modules (library - app)?

Tags: android

I'm building an Android Library Module from which I want to send notifications to its client (the app that is using it as dependency). I need to do it via intent. In the client's manifest I have a `xml <metadata>` element from where I can recover the name of the class that should intercept the intent. Problem is, when I try to send the intent I get an error saying that it could not load the class (I believe that it is due the fact that the classes are in different modules). What would be the best approach to notify my library's client?

**EDIT (RESOLVED)**

There is no problem loading the App class in the Library module (I was mistyping the package)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(searchableActivity));
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
sendIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, extraContent);
sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
```

Should do the job

Comment: you can load app class in the library. it not the problem of 'library-app' problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a method of going from App->Library then back from Library->App?